# Many to many relationship entity framework core db first

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, db-first

I have the entities Products and Tags. I have many to many relationship between the 2 tables, so I have tertiary table.

My Product Entity:

```
public class Product 
{
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public List<ProductTags> ProductTags { get; private set; }
}
```

My Tag Entity:

```
public class Tag
{
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
    public string Description { get; private set; }
    public List<ProductTags> ProductTags { get; private set; }
}
```

My ProductTags Entity:

```
public ProductTags
{
    public Guid ProductId { get; private set; }
    public Product Product { get; private set; }
    public Guid TagId { get; private set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; private set; }
}
```

How can I get my Tags related to my Product using Entity Framework Core?

**Sorry for errors, my knowledge in English is very low.**

Comment: I guess this may help you out. 
https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/many-to-many-relationship-configuration

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the latest version of `EF Core 2.1.4` doesn't support Many-to-Many feature as `EF 6.2` did out the box. Therefore, you should have 3rd table explicitly (ProductTags in your case).

You could find sample of mapping configuration [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#many-to-many)

How you can get Tags related to Product? There are dozens ways to do it, but the most appropriate (using EF and extension methods) will be:

```
var tagsByProduct = await context.ProductTags
    .Where(item => item.ProductId == 100500)
    .Select(item => item.Tag)
    .ToListAsync();
```

or

```
var tagsByProduct = await context.ProductTags
    .Where(item => item.Product.Name == "ProductName")
    .Select(item => item.Tag)
    .ToListAsync();
```

or

```
var tagsByProduct = await context.ProductTags
    .Where(item => item.Product.Name == "ProductName")
    .Select(item => new { Id = item.Tag.Id, Description = item.Tag.Description })
    .ToListAsync();
```

depend on you requirements.

Moreover, you could write joins explicitly, it will work a little bit faster.

Comment: @Evandro G. Santos if it works for you and solve you real problem, accept answer please. Otherwise, let me know and I will improve/extend it